# Drupal Facets Block Show everywhere (in non search page)

Tags: search

I use facets search and work well but i want to show block everywhere in website please for your help.

I try to create new views with my search index and add facets block in views but i get wrong url ?f[0]=field_places%3A72

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what module you are using with facetapi. If you are using search_api, then when creating the view you can add a view display of type "Facets Block" (like you would add a page, block or panel display).

Using that display you can add a facet block anywhere on your site, even on non search pages. And you can also set the search_path you want to redirect to when using the facet block.